# Automation and variables

Tags: calculations, automation, variable

For school and exams, time is at a premium. Copying expressions and pasting them in a third party calculator is too time consuming. Not to mention if you discover that you have made a mistake, and have to adjust all the expressions that depend on that result.

Is there a way I can turn something like this:

```
\mathdefine{a}[5]
\mathname{a} = \mathprint{a}

\mathcalc{4*a}
\mathexpression{} = \mathprint{}

\mathfuncadd{f, x}[a*x+10]
\mathfuncname{f, x} = \mathfuncdef{f}

\mathfuncname{f, 3} = \mathfunccalc{f, 3}

\mathfuncname{f, 3} = \mathfuncexpand{f, 3} = \mathfunccalc{f, 3}
```

Into this:
[image]

It should be fast to type and preferably the variables should be scoped to the current section, and if in a subsection it would inherit from it's parent.

Is there anything like this? A package or maybe a scripting language like Lua or python with a library?

Comment: how do you define "line this"? what features of the input syntax are you looking for, the suggested input syntax seems very verbose compared to normal tex input?

Comment: If it should be a scripting language, you could use LuaLaTeX and therein use Lua. Or use the package `pythontex` which can call Python. Writing something with LaTeX3 shouldn't be that hard, too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Consider it pseudo. The syntax doesn't have to be anything like that

Answer (score 2):

this shows a slightly different expansion step in the last case (I only have the case with a not substituted, or the fully evaluated term) other variants could be added if needed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\eval#1{{\def\var##1##2{##2}\def\*{*}\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\def\sym#1{{\def\var##1##2{##1}\def\*{\cdot}#1}}
\begin{document}

\def\a{\var{a}{5}}
$\sym{\a} = \eval{\a}$

\def\expr{4\*\a}
$\sym{\expr} =\eval{\expr}$

\def\f#1{\a\*#1+10}
$f(x)=\sym{\f{x}}$

$f(3) = \eval{\f{3}}$

$f(3) = \sym{\f{3}} = \eval{\f{3}}$


\end{document}
```